# Как написать обработчик на jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
document.querySelector('.main-header__input').addEventListener('keydown', function() {
showSearchBlock();
}, {
once: true
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я наткнулся на очень крутой метод. Это очень полезно, когда вы хотите привязать событие только один раз.

Вы можете найти документ здесь http://api.jquery.com/one/

Это то же самое, что и метод on, но отличается своим поведением, чтобы не придерживаться события для нескольких селекторов.

```js
$('body').one('keydown', '.main-header__input', showSearchBlock);
//or
$('.main-header__input').one('keydown', showSearchBlock);
```

Comment: Спасибо больше! Странно что я не заметил такую функцию рядом с `.on`.